# Dataframe groupby to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as below.

```
Month,Count,Parameter  
March 2015,1,40  
March 2015,1,10  
March 2015,1,1  
March 2015,1,25  
March 2015,1,50  
April 2015,1,15  
April 2015,1,1  
April 2015,1,1  
April 2015,1,15  
April 2015,1,15
```

I need to create a new table from above as shown below.

```
Unique Month,Total Count,<=30  
March 2015,5,3  
April 2015,5,5
```

The logic for new table is as follows. "Unique Month" column is unique month from original table and needs to sorted. "Total Count" is sum of "Count" column from original table for that particular month. "<=30" column is count of "Parameter <= 30" for that particular month.

Is there an easy way to do this in dataframes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, just check for `Parameter < 30` and then groupby:

```
(df.assign(le_30=df.Parameter.le(30))
   .groupby('Month', as_index=False) # pass sort=False if needed
   [['Count','le_30']].sum()
)
```

Or

```
(df.Parameter.le(30)
   .groupby(df['Month'])   # pass sort=False if needed
   .agg(['count','sum'])
)
```

Output:

```
    Month       Count   le_30
0   April 2015      5   5.0
1   March 2015      5   3.0
```

---

**Update**: as commented above, adding `sort=False` to `groupby` will respect your original sorting of `Month`. For example:

```
(df.Parameter.le(30)
   .groupby(df['Month'], sort=False)
   .agg(['count','sum'])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
        Month  count  sum
0  March 2015      5  3.0
1  April 2015      5  5.0
```

Comment: You forgot about sort by month.

Comment: @pierogi `groupby` sorts by `Month` by default. Here, the `Month` is text. Thanks. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Quang Hoang....Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to sort it by datetime?

Comment: @QuangHoang....Thanks. How about the case if original order is random and I need to sort them?

Comment: do `df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month']).dt.to_period('M')` first, then `groupby()` will sort it for your afterwards.